ffmpeg: "Error while filtering: No space left on device" - which device?
I get the following error: "Error while filtering: No space left on device". It causes the conversion to abort.
The process looks like this:
$ ffmpeg -xerror -fflags +discardcorrupt -i /video/input.ts -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map '0:a:1?' -f mpegts -s 720x576 -r 25 -vcodec mpeg2video -qscale:v 3.5 -acodec copy /video/output.mpeg
ffmpeg version 6.1.1-3ubuntu5
[..]
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[NULL @ 0x55f01a8ef6c0] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
[h264 @ 0x55f01a92c9c0] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
[h264 @ 0x55f01a92c9c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55f01a92c9c0] no frame!
[NULL @ 0x55f01a8ef6c0] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 3 times
[h264 @ 0x55f01b001fc0] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
[h264 @ 0x55f01b001fc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55f01b001fc0] no frame!
[NULL @ 0x55f01a8ef6c0] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
[h264 @ 0x55f01aab7bc0] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
[h264 @ 0x55f01aab7bc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55f01aab7bc0] no frame!
[NULL @ 0x55f01a8ef6c0] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
[h264 @ 0x55f01aa3c780] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
[h264 @ 0x55f01aa3c780] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55f01aa3c780] no frame!
[vist#0:1/h264 @ 0x55f01a9c3640] Error submitting packet to decoder: Invalid data found when processing input
[vist#0:1/h264 @ 0x55f01a9c3640] Error processing packet in decoder: Invalid data found when processing input
[vist#0:1/h264 @ 0x55f01a9c3640] Decoder thread returned error: Invalid data found when processing input
[h264 @ 0x55f01aaba180] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
[h264 @ 0x55f01aaba180] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55f01aaba180] no frame!
[vost#0:0/mpeg2video @ 0x55f01a936e40] No filtered frames for output stream, trying to initialize anyway.
[mpeg2video @ 0x55f01b023f80] MPEG-1/2 does not support 90000/1 fps
[vost#0:0/mpeg2video @ 0x55f01a936e40] Error while opening encoder - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height.
[NULL @ 0x55f01a8ef6c0] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 13 times
[aost#0:2/copy @ 0x55f01acf6d00] Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:2.
[aost#0:2/copy @ 0x55f01acf6d00] Error submitting a packet to the muxer
Error while filtering: No space left on device
[vist#0:1/h264 @ 0x55f01a9c3640] Decode error rate 1 exceeds maximum 0.666667
[aost#0:2/copy @ 0x55f01acf6d00] Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:2.
[aost#0:2/copy @ 0x55f01acf6d00] Error submitting a packet to the muxer
[out#0/mpegts @ 0x55f01a910300] Nothing was written into output file, because at least one of its streams received no packets.

The free space looks like this before starting the conversion, the file is in /video
+ df -h
Filesystem                                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay                                     40G   27G   11G  72% /
tmpfs                                       64M     0   64M   0% /dev
shm                                         64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/somedisk                       3.0T  2.8T   71G  98% /video
tmpfs                                      7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /proc/asound
tmpfs                                      7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                                      7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs                                      7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/firmware
tmpfs                                      7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/devices/virtual/powercap

As there is still a lot of free space on /video (the input is ~4GB and the expected output between 2..3GB), which device is the cause for the out-of-space error?
I'm doing this inside a docker container
Update 1
The exit code is sometimes 0, other times it ends with the text "Conversion failed!" and exit code 69. In the first case, the video is good until a point where all the errors happen. from there, only the audio stream continuous.
Update 2
the same file converts successfully in ffmpeg version 4.4.2 which is delivered with Ubuntu 22.04. The file has some errors, and that's very usual for recorded DVB signals. ffmpeg is expected to ignore these, and behaves as expected in this old version, so I would say we can ignore most of the above errors because they are also shown here, in a successful run:
+ ffmpeg -i /video/input.ts -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1? -f mpegts -s 720x576 -r 25 -vcodec mpeg2video -qscale:v 3.5 -acodec copy /video/input.hd2sd.~part~.mpeg
ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 2 referenced
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] sps_id 0 out of range
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 2 referenced
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 2 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 1 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] non-existing PPS 2 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55c578090440] no frame!
[mpegts @ 0x55c57806c840] start time for stream 0 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 0x55c57806c840] PES packet size mismatch
[mpegts @ 0x55c57806c840] Packet corrupt (stream = 2, dts = 6175170624).
[mpegts @ 0x55c57806c840] PES packet size mismatch
[mpegts @ 0x55c57806c840] Packet corrupt (stream = 3, dts = 6175166304).
Input #0, mpegts, from '/video/input.ts':
  Duration: 00:05:00.96, start: 68313.046933, bitrate: 10034 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Puls 8 HD
      service_provider: sunrise
  Stream #0:1[0xd0]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
  Stream #0:2[0xd1](deu): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
  Stream #0:3[0xdb](deu): Audio: ac3 ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 224 kb/s
  Stream #0:4[0xee](deu,deu): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
  No Program
  Stream #0:0[0x12]: Data: epg
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mpeg2video (native))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:2 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mpegts, to '/video/input.hd2sd.~part~.mpeg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top coded first (swapped)), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 90k tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 mpeg2video
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1(deu): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
  Stream #0:2(deu): Audio: ac3 ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 224 kb/s
/video/input.ts: corrupt decoded frame in stream 1
/video/input.ts: corrupt decoded frame in stream 1
    Last message repeated 1 times
/video/input.ts: corrupt decoded frame in stream 1
    Last message repeated 3 times
/video/input.ts: corrupt decoded frame in stream 1
    Last message repeated 3 times
/video/input.ts: corrupt decoded frame in stream 1
    Last message repeated 4 times
[mpegts @ 0x55c57806c840] PES packet size mismatch04:57.08 bitrate=3261.4kbits/s speed=8.42x    
[mpegts @ 0x55c57806c840] Packet corrupt (stream = 2, dts = 6175170624).
[mpegts @ 0x55c57806c840] PES packet size mismatch
[mpegts @ 0x55c57806c840] Packet corrupt (stream = 3, dts = 6175166304).
[h264 @ 0x55c578701900] error while decoding MB 13 60, bytestream -32
[h264 @ 0x55c578701900] concealing 996 DC, 996 AC, 996 MV errors in P frame
frame= 7471 fps=210 q=3.5 Lsize=  119090kB time=00:05:00.72 bitrate=3244.2kbits/s speed=8.43x    
video:99106kB audio:15230kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 4.158009%

Update 3
I did some debugging using strace -ff and found that there is not even one syscall returning an error other than these: ENOSYS, ECHILD, EINVAL, ENOTTY, ENOENT, EAGAIN, so I think it might even be the wrong text for something totally different.

That's a misleading error. There's a lot errors in decoding the H264 video stream and during that time, the output packets for the audio streams are getting buffered. The buffer limit has been reached which is when ffmpeg prints that error.

is there an option to skip these errors and continue with what follows that area? ffmpeg 4 also did this..

Map only the video stream and see if that finishes successfully.
